# Why a function works on mamp and not on hostserver?

Tags: wordpress, mamp, web-hosting

A function to call scripts for my wordpress website works on MAMP but not on the host server.

For my wordpress theme I have created two pages templates (page-portfolio.php and single-projects.php.)
In order to get specific scripts loaded for those pages I added the following code in the functions.php file

```
         <?php
    if (is_front_page()){
        wp_enqueue_script('flexslider-scripts');
        wp_enqueue_script('caroussel');
        wp_enqueue_script('menu');
            } elseif (is_page_template('page-portfolio.php')){
                wp_enqueue_script('menu');
                wp_enqueue_script('lightbox');
                } elseif (is_single()){
                wp_enqueue_script('menu');
                wp_enqueue_script('lightbox');
                }
                 else {
        wp_enqueue_script('menu');
        wp_enqueue_script('dropdown');
    }
?>
```

I am running into the following issue: everything is functionning when I am running my site locally on MAMP but when it is on my hostserver (OVH) the requested scripts don't load for the "is_single" condition (single-projects.php page).
What am I doing wrong/or missing?
Thank you very much in advance for your help
Kind Regards
Alain

Comment: do you have a console error? what's the php version on your hostserver?

Comment: Hello, the php version on my hostserver is 7.0 and I have to reload the faulty page to check for any console error..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **is_singular()** function.

[WP Codex: is_singular()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)

```
<?php
    if (is_front_page()){
        wp_enqueue_script('flexslider-scripts');
        wp_enqueue_script('caroussel');
        wp_enqueue_script('menu');
            } elseif (is_page_template('page-portfolio.php')){
                wp_enqueue_script('menu');
                wp_enqueue_script('lightbox');
                } elseif (is_singular('Custom_Post_Type_Name')){
                wp_enqueue_script('menu');
                wp_enqueue_script('lightbox');
                }
                 else {
        wp_enqueue_script('menu');
        wp_enqueue_script('dropdown');
    }
?>
```